# PHP PDO FETCH_ASSOC check value in next row before next while loop

Tags: php, pdo

Simple question, difficult to solve.
I use a while loop to display the results of mu PDO query, like this

```
while($data = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){ 
   //if the next row has an other value   
   //pass row to Class (to compose HTML object)
   //if the same do something else

}
```

Is there a way to see what the value is in the next row before ending the while loop? If the value is the same in the next row i want to do something...

Comment: use `fetchAll()` loop through all results, which you store in an array and then you can see if the next element is still set and if yes check the value or do something

Comment: Can you tell please what exactly you wish to do?

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this:

```
$i = 0;
while($data = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){ 
//Display row
echo '$data['test']['$i']';
if($data['test'][$i] == $data['test'][$i + 1]){
    //do something...
}
$i++;
}
```